# How to get graphical GUI output and user touch / keyboard / mouse input in a full system gem5 simulation?

Tags: gem5

Hopefully with `fs.py`, but not necessarily.

For example, I have some x86 BIOS example that draw a line on the screen on QEMU, and I'd like to see that work on gem5 too.

Interested in all archs.

https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15455.html

Answer (score 2):

**arm**

I have managed to get an image on the screen for ARM.

Here is a [highly automated setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/a0dd7ef9ca2a5c8577a41e6ada9a06df0428f911#graphic-mode-gem5) which does the following steps:

- grab the ARM gem5 Linux kernel v4.15 fork from: https://gem5.googlesource.com/arm/linux/ and use the config file arch/arm/configs/gem5_defconfig from there.

  The fork is required for the commit `drm: Add component-aware simple encoder` https://gem5.googlesource.com/arm/linux/ I believe, which adds the required option `CONFIG_DRM_VIRT_ENCODER=y`.

  The other required option is `CONFIG_DRM_HDLCD=y`, which enables the HDLCD ARM IP that manages the display: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0541c/CHDBAIDI.html
- run gem5 at 49f96e7b77925837aa5bc84d4c3453ab5f07408e
  with a command of type:

  ```
  M5_PATH='/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/common/gem5/system' \
  '/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/common/gem5/build/ARM/gem5.opt' \
  --debug-file=trace.txt \
  -d '/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/arm/gem5/m5out' \
  '/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/gem5/gem5/configs/example/fs.py' \
  --disk-image='/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/arm/buildroot/images/rootfs.ext2' \
  --kernel='/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/arm/buildroot/build/linux-custom/vmlinux' \
  --mem-size='256MB' \
  --num-cpus='1' \
  --script='/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/data/readfile' \
  --command-line='earlyprintk=pl011,0x1c090000 console=ttyAMA0 lpj=19988480 rw loglevel=8 mem=256MB root=/dev/sda console_msg_format=syslog nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y' \
  --dtb-file='/data/git/linux-kernel-module-cheat/out/common/gem5/system/arm/dt/armv7_gem5_v1_1cpu.dtb' \
  --machine-type=VExpress_GEM5_V1 \
  ```
- connect to the VNC server gem5 provides with your favorite client.

  On Ubuntu 18.04, I like:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install vinagre
  vinagre localhost:5900
  ```

  The port shows up on a gem5 message of type:

  ```
  system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900
  ```

  and it takes up the first free port starting from `5900`.

  Only raw connections are supported currently.

Outcome:

- after a few seconds, the VNC client shows up a little penguin on the screen! This is because our kernel was compiled with: `CONFIG_LOGO=y`.
- the latest frame gets dumped to `system.framebuffer.png`, and it also contains the little penguin.
- the Linux kernel dmesg shows on `telnet 3456` terminal a messages like:

  ```
  [    0.152755] [drm] found ARM HDLCD version r0p0
  [    0.152790] hdlcd 2b000000.hdlcd: bound virt-encoder (ops 0x80935f94)
  [    0.152795] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
  [    0.152799] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
  [    0.215179] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
  [    0.230389] hdlcd 2b000000.hdlcd: fb0:  frame buffer device
  [    0.230509] [drm] Initialized hdlcd 1.0.0 20151021 for 2b000000.hdlcd on minor 0
  ```

  which shows that the HDLCD was enabled.
- when we connect, gem5 shows on stdout:

  ```
  info: VNC client attached
  ```

TODO: also get a shell working. Currently I only have a the little penguin, and my keystrokes do nothing. Likely have to tweak the `console=` kernel parameter or setup a tty console there on init? `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y` is set. Maybe the answer is contained in: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt

**aarch64**

The `aarch64` gem5 defconfig does not come with all required options, e.g. `CONFIG_DRM_HDLCD=y`.

Adding the following options, either by hacking or with a config fragment made it work:

```
CONFIG_DRM=y
CONFIG_DRM_HDLCD=y
CONFIG_DRM_VIRT_ENCODER=y
```